# Django (drf) dynamic permissions from BasePermission

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I want to have easy way to check if somebody is owner or admin of `post`, `proposal` and so on he's trying to edit \ delete.

So, every time I use `IsAuthenticated` permission and in the method of `ModelViewSet` I get instance and check if `instance.author` or sometimes `instance.owner` is the user who requested it (`request.user == instance.owner` on some objects it's `request.user == instance.author`).

**Question**

The main question is: how can I create permission class that can check this kind of ownership with dynamic user attribute name on instance?

**One of mine solutions** (not the best, i think)

I've created function that take user attribute instance name returns permission class:

```
def is_owner_or_admin_permission_factory(owner_prop_name):
    class IsOwnerOrAdmin(BasePermission):
        def has_permission(self, request, view, *args, **kwargs):
            instance = view.get_object()
            try:
                owner = getattr(instance, owner_prop_name)
            except AttributeError:
                return False
            return (
                request.user and request.user.id and (owner == request.user or request.user.is_staff)
            )

    return IsOwnerOrAdmin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also been frustrated over the same exact problem for days, and I've managed to find a suitable work-around (at least for me, of course), when dealing with multiple models with different lookup names for user attributes.

The work-around was something like this, in the `ModelViewSet` defined a separate attribute `user_lookup_kwarg` in the view, which could be used for checking the appropriate permissions.

Eg,

```
class YourViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = YourModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = YourSerializer
    user_lookup_kwarg = 'user' #or 'account/created_by' whatever.
```

Now, your `permission_class` would be somewhat like this,

```
class CustomPermission(BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        try:
            return request.user.is_superuser or getattr(obj, view.user_lookup_kwarg) == request.user
        except:
            return False
        return request.user.is_superuser
```

You only just need to override `has_object_permission()` method to check instance level permissions.

Comment: One moment: when you check `request.user.is_superuser` and its returns `True`, it will be returned from method, if it's `False` and the second argument raise exception you can just return `False`, because  `request.user.is_superuser` must already be `False`.

Comment: Also, I think its better to check that the user is authorized, because (in most cases) `AnonymousUser` can't be owner of object, so he needs to be authorized.

Comment: You said `IsAuthenticated` is your default permission, then you only just need to add that in your permission class. Donot try to push everything into single class, divide it and reuse.

Comment: For your former question, if `request.user.is_superuser` return `False`, then if you define `user_lookup_kwarg`, the exception won't be raised, but the result of expression would be returned.

Answer (score 0):

For people who found this question my variant:

```py
class IsInGroup:
    """
    Usage:

    class MyView(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
        permission_classes = (IsInGroup('Admins'),)
    """

    def __new__(cls, group_name):
        return type(
            f'IsInGroup{group_name}',
            (IsAuthenticated,),
            {
                'group_name': group_name,
                **{key: value for key, value in cls.__dict__.items() if not key.startswith('__')},
            },
        )

    group_name: str

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.groups.filter(name=self.group_name).exists()
```